# Difference between excel / TTR standard deviations

Tags: r, excel

Using TTR to work out a 2 day standard deviation. 
I also did the same in excel.

They are largley the same, except in TTR, I recieve values:

```
1.00485917355762E-14
```

Where excel has a 0 in its place. What is the meaning of the above value? Something raised to the power of 14? If excel says its supposed to be 0, why would i see this, who is correct?

```
Close   TTR package stdev, n = 2    Excel stdev, n = 2
    43.79979    NA                  NA
    44.04865    0.175970594 0.175970594
    44.17308    0.087985297 0.087985297
    44.54638    0.263962961 0.263962961
    44.79524    0.175970594 0.175970594
    44.79524    1.00E-14    0
    44.79524    1.00E-14    0
    44.42195    0.26395589  0.26395589
    44.54638    0.087985297 0.087985297
    44.79524    0.175970594 0.175970594
    44.42195    0.26395589  0.26395589
    43.30206    0.791881813 0.791881813
    43.30206    0   0
    43.17764    0.087978226 0.087978226
    43.30206    0.087978226 0.087978226
    43.55093    0.175977665 0.175977665
    43.55093    0   0
    44.04865    0.351941187 0.351941187
    44.17308    0.087985297 0.087985297
```

I should comment that this discrepancy disappears over a larger n period. > 3 and the problem is non existent. Appreciate that a 2/3 stdev is quite small comparison

Comment: `1.004E-14` means `1.004 * 10^(-14)` (10 to the minus 14), it's a very small number and is very close to 0. You might be getting very small differences due to floating point precision issue (Excel treats floats differently to R), I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: Great - thank you for the answer here. Essentially so small it is rounded out in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is E notation, which is completely standard on computers and calculators. It's a compact way of giving scientific notation in a single line without superscripts.

`3.2E4` means 3.2 x 10^4 while `1.2E-3` means 1.2 x 10^-3

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation for more details

As a result 1.00485917355762E-14 means 0.0000000000000100485917355762, which is extremely close to 0, and which Excel would presumably just round to 0.